# Convert text file to yaml in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have a text file in the below format:

```
{'Server Type: ABCDDEER' :['name: abcd01t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.52', 'tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDEER' :['name: abcd02t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.53', 'tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDEER' :['name: abcd03t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.54', 'tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDEER' :['name: abcd04t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.55', 'tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd1t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.36', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd2t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.37', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd3t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.38', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd4t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.39', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd5t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.47', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd6t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.41', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd7t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.42', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd8t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.48', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP2']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd9t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.44', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1']},
{'Server Type: ABCDDPP' :['name: abcd0t' ,'IP: 127.12.32.49', 'tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP2']}
```

Is there any way we can directly convert to yaml so that it could be in the below format:

---

```
"Server Type: ABCDDEER"
: 
  - "name: abcd01t"
  - "IP: 127.12.32.52"
  - "tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER1"

  - "name: abcd02t"
  - "IP: 127.12.32.53"
  - "tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER2"

  - "name: abcd03t"
  - "IP: 127.12.32.54"
  - "tags: ALL, APP,EER, REER2"

"Server Type: ABCDDPP"
: 
  - "name: abcd1t"
  - "IP: 127.12.32.36"
  - "tags: ALL, APP,PP,  PP1"
```

etc

So that the serverTyoe is the header and whatever with same serverType comes inside of it.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: The format below is not valid YAML; the colons must be on the same line as the key unless you use `?` for explicitly marking the keys. Even then, PyYAML does not allow you to insert empty lines inside a block sequence. You'd need to format it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `yaml` module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
import yaml

result = {}
with open("data.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        d = ast.literal_eval(line.strip().rstrip(","))
        for k, v in d.items():
            result.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)     #groupby header

with open("outfile.yaml", 'w') as yfile:
    yaml.dump(result, yfile)
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh! Appreciate the quick help!